# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined ionic 4

Tags: android, angular, authentication, ionic4

Hi im working with a json local file have two users:

```
{
    "usuarios": [
        {
            "usuario": "david",
            "clave": "123456",
            "username": "David Ortega Mazzini"
        },
        {
            "usuario": "prueba",
            "clave": "123456",
            "username": "David Ortega Mazzini"
        }
    ]
}
```

and one service retrieves information about this file.

```
  getData(user:string,clave:string):Observable<UserOptions[]> {
    return this.http.get<UserOptions[]>(this.dataUrl)
 }
```

and the login.page.ts call this service

```
this._logic.getData(user,password)
    .subscribe(
      (res) => {this.usuarios.username = res[0].username;
        if (this.usuarios.username.toString === null){
          this.showError()
        } else {
          console.log(this.usuarios.username.toString);
          this.router.navigateByUrl("home");
        }
      },
      (error) => {console.log(JSON.stringify(error));}
    )
```

but shows me this error

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined ionic 4

what im doing wrong? thanks a lot!!

Comment: what is **this.usuarios**  and what is the response of your **getData** method ???

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the service passes down directly the same json you showing in your question, `res[0]` is not value in the json.

res is the object `{usuarios:[{...}, {...}]}`. Simply put, res is an **object**, not an **array**. If you are trying to access the first element in the usuarios array, you need to call it `res.usuarios[0].username`.

Another possible explanation is that `this.usuarios` is not defined before trying to set the username property.

Comment: my definition usuarios its these:  usuarios: UserOptions = { usuario:'', username: '', clave: ''};

Comment: UserOption its a interface. Then Interface has a username, usuario,clave